# Get specific part of string with regular expression

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a string like so `"blah blah blah blah @[Dave Battersby](Person:292) blah blibbidy blah"`

I want to strip out the unreadable parts so just the text remains using a regular expression. I have tried this regular expression `(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])` but this just gives a collection of the things inside the `[]` Ie `Dave Battersby`

What I need is to return the string `"blah blah blah blah Dave Battersby blah blibbidy blah"`

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing a simple replace of the characters that you don't want with an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear if the pattern `@[name](id info)` is fixed, but if so, the following should work:

```
Dim input = "blah blah blah blah @[Dave Battersby](Person:292) blah blibbidy blah"
Dim output = Regex.Replace(input, "@\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)", "$1")
```

This searches for the full pattern, capturing the name part, and replaces the matched text with just the name.

Comment: Thanks, the pattern is fixed - with the exception of Person: - this could say other things such as "team", "page"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no square brackets or parenthesis in your "blah blah blah" text, the following should work:

```
string myStr = "blah blah blah blah @[Dave Battersby](Person:292) blah blibbidy blah";
Regex.Replace(myStr, @"@\[(.*)\].*\)", "$1");
```